# How to use ffmpeg Library in electron？

Tags: c++, node.js, ffmpeg, uwp, electron

I use ffmpeg in electronic, but uwp can't use the command line, so I want to use ffmpeg library instead, and install "FFI NaPi". After testing, it can call the library, but I don't know C language and how to call ffmpeg library. Can anyone help me?

This is my test of "ffi napi". It can really succeed：

c++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b) {

    return 20;
};
```

electron js:

```
 var ffi = require('ffi-napi');
    var libm = ffi.Library('Dll1.dll', {
      'add': [ 'int', [ 'int', 'int' ] ],
    });
    
    var rel = libm.add(1,2); // 20
    console.error('rel:',rel);
```

This is the download website of ffmpeg library：
https://github.com/wang-bin/avbuild

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
[enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTMhK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxsw4.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mDLx.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAjPE.png
```

I have no programming knowledge of C + + and do not know how to call these libraries. I just want to edit a video, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c -copy b.mp4
```

Comment: Your question sounds confusing. Electron is not a UWP app. If you want to use Electron and FFMPEG then look up native modules in electron

Comment: Have you looked into [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm)? This seems to be what you need

Comment: hi,Electronic can be packaged into uwp through electronic windows store